# Order of 301 redirects

Tags: apache

When I add the redirects

```
Redirect 301 /leistungen/werbetechnik/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/ https://mywebsite.com/werbetechnik-wird-jesto-werbetechnik-gmbh/
Redirect 301 /leistungen/werbetechnik/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/prospekthalter-prospektstaender/ https://mywebsite.com/werbetechnik-wird-jesto-werbetechnik-gmbh/
```

The second redirect does not work it will redirect as follows:

```
https://mywebsite.com/werbetechnik-wird-jesto-werbetechnik-gmbh/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/prospekthalter-prospektstaender/
```

As you can see it redirects correctly but adds
 `/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/prospekthalter-prospektstaender/` to the end which is a part of the original URL

But when I change the order to

```
Redirect 301 /leistungen/werbetechnik/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/prospekthalter-prospektstaender/ https://mywebsite.com/werbetechnik-wird-jesto-werbetechnik-gmbh/
Redirect 301 /leistungen/werbetechnik/point-of-sale-und-messebedarf/ https://mywebsite.com/werbetechnik-wird-jesto-werbetechnik-gmbh/
```

The redirect works

Can somebody explain me why this happens?

I use an .htaccess file in a Linux environment on a windows server - as I was told

Thanks

Comment: Describe what happens when it 'does not work' and make sure you share what software you are using to configure this. (looks like Apache?)

Comment: I would assume that some other directive interferes here. Those two lines alone will _not_ result in the behavior you describe. In general directives are getting applied from top to bottom. Which means that you should implement more specialized exceptions further up in files and more general rules further down. So the other way round as you currently do it.